# Is it possible to have two accounts from different regions on a PS4?

Tags: region-lock, ps4

I used to have two accounts on my PS3, one in the UK and another in the USA.

I used each one of them to download Exclusive Content which was unavailable in each region. Sometimes I would buy games from USA, sometimes from UK. In PS3, it wasn't a problem. I can play both of them without any problem. Is this possible in PS4 too?

So let's say I activate two of my accounts in my PS4 and set both of them as primary account (I think it's possible). Can I play all of my games in UK account? For example if I buy a hard copy of Assassin's Creed Black Flag from USA, can I play it with my UK account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, it's all the same as on PS3. Primary account shares all content with other accounts and [you can have multiple primary accounts](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5059). Excerpt:

> If a user activates a system with his or her account, **other users on** 
>   **the system can use applications** and enjoy some PlayStation Plus
>   benefits from that account, even if that user is not logged in.
>
> If **multiple users** have activated the system as their primary PS4
>   system, deactivate it for each user.